# 502 Bad Gateway: Registered endpoint failed to handle the request. : Python

Tags: python, flask, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to deploy an app developed using python and flask on ibm cloud.
The app is pushed and starts as well, but when i visit the link I get the error:

> #### 502 Bad Gateway: Registered endpoint failed to handle the request

My manifest file looks like this:

```
applications:
- name: people
memory: 256M
command: python main.py
random-route: true
services:
- eapenDB2
```

My procfile looks like this:

```
web: people
```

What the console looks like after pushing the app:
[image: CLI]

These are the logs I have. I hope they're helpful:
[image: Logs1]
[image: Logs2]
[image: Logs3]
[image: Logs4]
[image: Logs5]
Sorry about the long post. But really hoping you can help me.

Comment: Please post the answer here if you are able to solve. I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Python requires `__init__.py` in every folder if we modularize the code into multiple folders. In our case we had run.py in the root and rest of the code inside multiple folders in "src" folder. 
A good article on that:

https://damyanon.net/post/flask-series-structure/